# MySQL: Update a running "account balance" based on another table

Tags: mysql

**Fiddle:**
Please see this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af05d8/1/0

**Scenario:** I need to update customer account balances based on a table listing the jobs/services received. Each customer account should be charged a given price for each job/service, by adding a new row to the Ledger table with the new customer account balance (previous_balance - price).

**Issue:** The fiddle / queries work fine when a customer only has one job in the table requiring a balance update. However when the customer has more than one row in the jobs table, the actual account balance isn't used for each job - the original account balance is used for all jobs instead.

*edit to clarify*: the issue has been identified by spencer5973 in answer #1. The SELECT is running against the table as it sits at the start of the statement. New rows added to the Ledger by the query are not taken into account for subsequent SELECTs, meaning the correct running total is not SELECTed for customers with more than one row in the jobs table.

**Detail:**

*tmptblLedger*: a running list of account balances (Ledger entries) for all Customers. Each time the Customer account balance is changed (payment, purchases etc), a new row is added. Each row records the opening balance - which is the same as the previous closing balance - and the new closing balance.

*edit to clarify:* the Customer account balance can be reduced by paying for a Job (as shown in the fiddle and this question), or increased by a payment to account (not shown), or otherwise altered by a transaction unrelated to the Job table. This prevents spencer5973's answer below from working. The Ledger is the one single authoritative source of all transactions/adjustments to customer account balances.

*tmptblJobs*: a "chargeable work done" tracking table. Each time the Customer has some work done (a job), a row is added. The row specifies how many jobs were done, and the price per job.

The requirement is pretty simple - each Customer's Ledger has to be updated to reflect the jobs done. In pseudocode:

```
foreach(row in tmptblJobs)
{
    get row.Customer ID;
    get Customer's current account balance (MAX LedgerID in Ledger table)
    new_balance = subtract (row.NumberOfJobs * row.PricePerJob) from current balance
    write new row with new_balance to ledger table
}
```

The queries work correctly when a Customer has only one row in the Jobs table.

The issue seems to be that when a Customer has more than 1 row in the Jobs table, the new row written to the Ledger table (new balance) is ignored for subsequent rows in the Jobs table. Instead, the original balance before the query ran is used - like the result is cached.

I can believe I'm missing some SQL or feature to make this work, but I don't know what...

**Table structure and sample data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptblLedger;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptblJobs;

CREATE TABLE `tmptblLedger` (
  `LedgerID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique transaction ID',
  `Timestamp` DATETIME,
  `BalanceOpen` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last balance for customer before this record was created',
  `BalanceClose` float NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Balance now that record has been created = BalanceOpen + Adjustment Amount',
  `Customer_CustID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE `tmptblLedger` 
    MODIFY `LedgerID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1,
    ADD UNIQUE KEY (`LedgerID`);

/* some representative data, this example only uses Customer_CustID == 1). All ledgers start at zero, this example has a second ledger entry for CustID == 1 to put the balance to 100 */
INSERT INTO `tmptblLedger` (`Timestamp`, `BalanceOpen`, `BalanceClose`, `Customer_CustID`)  VALUES (NOW(), 0, 0, 1), (NOW(), 0, 100, 1), (NOW(), 0, 5, 2), (NOW(), 0, 7, 3);

CREATE TABLE `tmptblJobs` (
  `ScheduledTargetID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_CustID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NumberOfJobsCompleted` int UNSIGNED,
  `PricePerJob` float UNSIGNED
);
ALTER TABLE `tmptblJobs`
    MODIFY `ScheduledTargetID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1,
    ADD UNIQUE KEY(`ScheduledTargetID`);

/* insert 3 jobs for CustID 1, and an example 1 job for CustID 2 to represent real world data */
INSERT INTO `tmptblJobs` (`Customer_CustID`, `NumberOfJobsCompleted`, `PricePerJob`)    VALUES (1, 2, 5), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1);
```

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `tmptblLedger` (`Timestamp`, `BalanceOpen`, `BalanceClose`, `Customer_CustID`)
    SELECT
        NOW(),
        derivedLedger.LedgerCurrentBalance,
        derivedLedger.LedgerCurrentBalance - ( @TotalPrice:=(tmptblJobs.NumberOfJobsCompleted * tmptblJobs.PricePerJob) ) AS NEWBALANCE,
        tmptblJobs.Customer_CustID
    FROM
        (
            /* Obtain current balance for each CustID, using newest LedgerID */
            SELECT
                derivedNewestLedgerRow.LedgerCustID,
                tmptblLedger.BalanceClose AS LedgerCurrentBalance /* current balance == closing balance of newest ledger entry */
            FROM
                tmptblLedger
            RIGHT JOIN
            (
                /* Obtain newest LedgerID for each CustID */
                SELECT
                    tmptblLedger.Customer_CustID AS LedgerCustID,
                    MAX(LedgerID) AS NewestCustLedgerID
                FROM
                    tmptblLedger
                GROUP BY tmptblLedger.Customer_CustID
            ) as derivedNewestLedgerRow ON LedgerID = NewestCustLedgerID
        ) as derivedLedger
    INNER JOIN tmptblJobs ON tmptblJobs.Customer_CustID = derivedLedger.LedgerCustID
    WHERE 1;

/* LegerID rows 5, 6 and 7 will now all start from a BalanceOpen of 100, instead of BalanceOpen 100, then 90 (for ScheduledTargetID 1), then 87 (ScheduledTargetID 2), then 86 (ID 3)... */ 
SELECT * FROM tmptblLedger;
```

**Results:**

```
LedgerID    Timestamp   BalanceOpen BalanceClose    Customer_CustID
1   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    0   0   1
2   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    0   100 1
3   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    0   5   2
4   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    0   7   3
5   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    100 90  1
6   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    100 97  1
7   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    100 99  1
8   2019-03-06T16:03:11Z    5   4   2
```

Rows 5, 6 and 7 are wrong. BalanceClose should be:

```
Row 5 = 90
Row 6 = 87
Row 7 = 86
```

Comment: Incidentally, it seems fantastically unlikely that anything called 'balance' would be FLOAT. It's why DECIMAL was invented!

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks, yes you're right I can drop the INSERT. So as you said and I surmised in the question, the SELECT is against the table at the start of the statement. So how do I solve this? Surely updating an account balance like this is a really common requirement?

Comment: Why?  Why not just record every individual transaction with a customer id and a value, then calculate the balance when you need it? That's how a ledger normally works.

Comment: @JeffUK you mean instead of recording balance open and close, just record adjustment amount and timestamp? That means for any given requirement to calculate "current" balance, every single row per CustID must be queried. To calc overall business ledger balance, every single row in the table must be queried. Tracking the balance open and close means only latest row per CustID needs to be queried.

Comment: To get our head wrapped around how SQL works, we need to think in terms of *sets* of rows.  We think in terms of a set of rows that are needed, and what operations to perform on the set, rather than thinking in terms of processing "each row".

Comment: @spencer7593 thank you, I'm thinking how to explain the wider scenario as the fiddle & q are simplified. In the full scenario, the reason not to add a single row for (5,6,7,N...) is that each ledger entry is associated with the job that charged it. I.e.: there is additional foreign key in tmptblLedger for tmptblJobs.ScheduledTargetID. This allows a track of "what job resulted in what ledger entry/balance adjustment"

Comment: @spencer7593 we can order the jobs in any way required, however the ScheduledTargetID is always sequential. So it makes sense that we work through tmptblJobs using ScheduledTargetID ascending, as that creates ledger entries in order. In the full live code, each row in tmptblJobs does have a timestamp to record when the work was done, because the time period could be anything from a few hours to several days. But the purpose of the timestamp is a reference - it's the order of the ScheduledTargetID that controls the order in which the Ledger should be updated.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is "how do we force mysql to always perform the SELECT on the 'current' ledger table instead of on the table as at the start of the statement".

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I mean. It’s how every accounting system I’ve ever seen works (sage, oracle, Microsoft dynamics, sap, etc,) and with proper indexing the performance is not an issue on any modern dbms. If you’re doing this for performance reasons you’re optimising prematurely.

Comment: @JeffUK thank you for the info, I'll consider this. I'm still v surprised that it's done the way you suggest, as it requires every single row to be scanned to get the current business ledger balance versus my approach, which only requires MAX(LedgerID) to be scanned. Changing this is a significant architectural change so I'd prefer to try and solve the problem as described first, but thanks for the information and suggestion.

Comment: If you’re doing a table scan to sum() you don’t have proper indexes!

Comment: @JeffUK I can understand that for "simple" requests by a client side to get current balances etc. But as soon as you need anything more complex ("show me all the ledger entries between date X and Y where product N was purchased, joined to another table with pricing info for products"), the resulting db queries to parse the info becomes more complex and costly. Again versus my way which provides a running total no matter which row you pull out. Am I totally missing something? I'm not an SQL expert by any stretch, I know enough to get by.

Comment: @Endeavor99 how on earth would you do that with your structure?  With a simple list of transactions that would be trivial...

Comment: @JeffUK the table structures in my post and fiddle are significantly simplified! I'm just talking about the principle of either being able to immediately have the point in time balance from selecting any one row, vs your suggestion which I understand to require selecting and summing N rows to get the same result. The problem might be that I don't understand the performance implications/benefits from your way with index, as I said I'm not an expert! Would you be able to explain please?

Answer (score 1):

*comment1:* "With the `INSERT INTO tmptblLedger SELECT ... FROM tmptblLedger ...`statement, the rows being inserted will *not* be read by the `SELECT`. The `SELECT` is running against the table as it sits at the start of the statement. We can run just the SELECT (without the INSERT). That's the set of rows that's would be inserted."

*comment2:* "One approach to fixing this would be to aggregate the jobs i.e. `SUM(qty*unit_price)` into a *single* row for each customer. So instead of adding *three* rows (5,6,7) for custid=1, (one for each job), we would add a *single* row with balance_open=100 and balance_close=86. (100-((2*5)+(1*3)+(1*1)) )

*comment3:* "If we need to add three rows (5,6,7) for custid=1, then the open_balance is not just the balance from the latest ledger id. We need to include adjustments for previous jobs. There has to be some way to uniquely order the jobs,... I'm thinking in terms of a correlated subquery that gets the SUM(qty*unit_price) for the jobs that preceded the current row. We subtract that from the balance from the latest ledger row, to get the balance_open for the current row."

---

It's not possible to get the `SELECT` to read rows that weren't there when the statement started executing, not in the context of a single SQL statement. (We can get deep into the weeds in a discussion of transaction isolation levels, and allowing "dirty reads" in the context of a transaction which opens the possibility of some uncommitted changes to get read, but that's not reliable, there's no guarantee. Even with isolation level allowing dirty reads, that still wouldn't happen in the execution of the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement.

There is no way to "fix" the inability of a SQL statement to read rows that are being inserted as it executes. It's not a problem that needs to be solved. This restriction is actually a design feature of relational databases; it actually solves problems that could crop up if that were to happen.

Bottom line, there isn't a way to get that SELECT to read rows being inserted.

What we need to do instead is get the values from other rows being inserted, and to do that, we have to re-calculate the values from the previous rows, and include those in the results of the current row.

We can do that with a correlated subquery.

Currently, the SELECT statement is of the form:

```
SELECT NOW()
     , d.ledgercurrentbalance
     , d.ledgercurrentbalance - (j.numberofjobscompleted * j.priceperjob) AS newbalance
     , j.customer_custid
FROM ( SELECT n.ledgercustid
            , t.balanceclose AS ledgercurrentbalance /* current balance == closing balance of newest ledger entry */
         FROM ( /* Obtain newest LedgerID for each CustID */
                SELECT tmptblLedger.Customer_CustID AS LedgerCustID
                     , MAX(LedgerID) AS NewestCustLedgerID
                  FROM tmptblLedger l
                 GROUP BY l.customer_custid
              ) n
         LEFT 
         JOIN tmptblLedger t
           ON t.ledgerid = n.newestcustledgerid
     ) d
JOIN tmptblJobs j 
  ON j.customer_custid = d.ledgercustid
```

We could introduce a correlated subquery to get the `SUM(qty*price)` for the previous jobs for a customer. Given that `scheduledtargetid` is unique in the jobs table, we can use that for ordering.

Something like this:

```
SELECT NOW()                                             AS `Timestamp`
     , b.balanceclose - b.prevjobs_cost                  AS `BalanceOpen`
     , b.balanceclose - b.prevjobs_cost - b.currjob_cost AS `BalanceClose`
     , b.customer_custid                                 AS `Customer_CustID`
  FROM ( SELECT j.scheduledtargetid
              , j.customer_custid
              , d.balanceclose
              , ( j.numberofjobscompleted * j.priceperjob ) AS currjob_cost

              , IFNULL(
                  ( /* correlated subquery to get total cost of previous jobs */
                    SELECT SUM(p.numberofjobscompleted * p.priceperjob)
                      FROM `tmptblJobs` p
                     WHERE p.customer_custid   = j.customer_custid
                       AND p.scheduledtargetid < j.scheduledtargetid
                  )
                ,0) AS prevjobs_cost

           FROM ( SELECT n.ledgercustid
                       , t.balanceclose
                    FROM ( /* latest ledgerid for each custid */
                           SELECT l.customer_custid AS ledgercustid
                                , MAX(l.ledgerid) AS newestcustledgerid
                             FROM `tmptblLedger` l
                            GROUP BY l.customer_custid
                         ) n
                    LEFT
                    JOIN `tmptblLedger` t
                      ON t.ledgerid = n.newestcustledgerid
                ) d
           JOIN `tmptblJobs` j
             ON j.customer_custid = d.ledgercustid
       ) b
 ORDER
    BY b.customer_custid
     , b.scheduledtargetid
```

---

Some issues not addressed:

There will need to be at least one row in the target `tmptblLedger` table for each customer. This query won't generate new rows for that customer if a row doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for working on this, appreciate it. That's a clever solution but unfortunately it won't solve the prob. Please can I highlight this from my question (second sentence under "detail"): "(payment, purchases etc), a new row is added". The Ledger is the authority on the account balance - although Jobs can decrement it, other actions such as purchases of items (not services/jobs), goodwill credits, payments to balance, refunds can also increment and decrement it. So we can't just sum the Jobs table. Summing all "tracking" tables is possible but very complex.

Comment: can I clarify this: _"There is no way to "fix" the inability [...] it actually solves problems"_. What are the problems it solves? Are we saying that my specific scenario is actually unsolvable in SQL, and I need to pull the data into code then write it back? I can do that easily, but it will be inefficient. I also worked out a partial solution using mysql variables but again it's highly complex and doesn't fully work for my scenario.

Comment: @Endeavor99: In relational database, operations happen on *sets* of data.A set can containing *one* row, the typical `WHERE pkcol = ?`. A set can also contain zero rows, or it contain multiple rows. One of the important features of relational database is that when we operate on a *set* of data we are operating on a consistent view of the data. Other concurrent operations on the same rows should not effect or be visible to our transaction. Relational databases do a lot of work obtaining and releasing locks, and retaining "as of" versions of the blocks for other transactions, and for rollback.

Comment: The answer remains the same: it's not possible to process a set of data and have the set of rows mutate (to included newly added rows) as the operation proceeds. If you need to look at a *different* set of rows for each row that is processed, then  the answer would be to process each row individually, with a separate SQL statement, then each statement execution will be able to view the set of rows that it needs.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, so my only options here are to either use a complex query with mysql variables to track and group CustIDs, or to pull the data back to PHP then manipulate and write new rows to Ledger as required - which is your answer of "process each row individually with separate SQL". Frustratingly inefficient, but will have to do. Thanks!